# Debian 9 / old version of openssl

Tags: debian, software-installation, openssl

I need to install openssl 1.0 on debian 9 (stretch). when I run apt-get install openssl , version 1.1 is installed by default.

how can I change the repository in order to install an old version of openssl?

Comment: You will probably instead need to download openssl sources by yourself and compile it to make sure you have exactly what you need. I hope that you have valid reasons to need version 1.0 (what broke in 1.1 that you can not use it?) because compiling such things by itself is not funny.

Comment: Can you please summarize how to do it? I'm still new to debian :)

Comment: Check which versions your `sources.list` entries can see - `apt-cache madison openssl`.  If you want a non-default version, use `apt-get install packagename=specificversion` - ie, `apt-get install openssl=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4` (on my Mint 18 system)

Comment: why do you exactly need an old openssl version?

Comment: Do you need the old version of the programs (and if-so why) or do you just need the old library?

Answer (score 10):

As others have mentioned, if you can use OpenSSL 1.1 instead, that would be best.

However, if you really do need OpenSSL 1.0, the answer depends on your exact requirement. If you only need the OpenSSL library, and if version 1.0.2 is appropriate, then you can install `libssl1.0.2` from Debian 9 and be done with it.

If you need version 1.0 of the `openssl` tool, or version 1.0.1 of the library, the simplest option on Debian 9 is to install it from Debian 8 (which still receives security updates, and will until 2020). To do so, create a file called `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list` containing the following:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

Then run `sudo apt update`, and `apt install openssl/jessie` for the `openssl` tool, or `apt install libssl1.0.0` for the library.

Contrary to some people’s claims, you don’t risk breaking your system by installing these packages, thanks to package management and properly-defined package dependencies.

Comment: With the risk of major breakage among all packages, as other installed Debian 9 packages will have a dependency on `libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0)`...

Comment: @Patrick, no, because `libssl1.0.0` is co-installable with `libssl1.1`. I have this exact setup on a couple of systems, one in particular which is used to track the 1.0-to-1.1 transition, and it works fine.

Comment: TBH I find it rather amusing that you claim this risks breaking other packages, while you recommend recompiling from source in your own answer...

Comment: I clearly did not wrote things correctly enough if that is your interpretation of my answer. You clearly miss both my intent and my explanation, sorry about that.

Comment: Version 1.0.1 is not supported anymore by upstream OpenSSL. Only 1.0.2 is, until end of 2019. `libssl1.0.0` in your repository seems to be a port of openssl `1.0.1t` in fact . No trace of a 1.0.2 version. Based on https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libssl1.0&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all there seem to be a backport of some `1.0.2` version in `jessie-backports` repository.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you will find older versions of a software, such as `openssl`, for newer version of your distribution, as most of the time it will not make sense, as newer versions should fix problems, etc. (they are exceptions of course). Alternatively, why not use Debian 8 directly?

But have a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/108080/ubuntu-debian-show-list-of-available-versions-of-a-specific-package and the `apt-show-versions` and `rmadison` tools.

So first you have to really make sure you absolutely need an old version. You do not detail your use case, so hard to give good advises.

What you can always do is install from the sources themselves... but it is not a simple task. The compilation by itself may not be a huge deal, but you need to install it separately from the system part, like in `/usr/local` and for something typically used as a library by other applications, you need to **recompile** the other applications to make sure to use your local version instead of the system one. You will have a similar problem if you happen to find an old package that suits your needs: other applications on the system relying on `openssl` might not work anymore and the software list on your system may be broken.

In short make really absolutely sure without alternatives that you need to do that!

And if you never compiled anything on a Linux system (it will be mostly the same in all distributions), `openssl` is maybe not the best candidate for first try.

Go to https://www.openssl.org/source/ and download the version you need (I do hope that you find it here, because otherwise you will have an even bigger problem).

As with other software, start with `README` that basically tells you to read `INSTALL`.
And it boils down to:

```
 $ ./config
 $ make
 $ make test
 $ make install
```

But please make sure to read the file before doing anything as it has important information, like where the software will be installed.

Then you need to be able to use the result in whatever application you need it... but you do not give context of your question, so I can not help you.
Often you will need to recompile other software with a flag such as `--with-openssl=DIRECTORY` to force it to use your version instead of the normal system one.

Comment: The API of `openssl` changes a lot between versions...if some old software needs it, a new version is not a drop in replacement.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro can you pinpoint a specific breakage/change of API between 1.0 and 1.1? I agree in general with your assertion but in that specific case it is better to upgrade the old software (again, general vow, not always trivial indeed) instead of downgrading openssl, especially for such a security critical code with so many bugs discovered in the past years...

Comment: I have not said it a good idea to use the old versions, and I fully agree with you. I know there are *huge* API differences between some versions mainly because of dealing with freeradius, however I am not that familiar with the openssl libraries.

Comment: There are huge differences between the APIs of OpenSSL 1.0 and 1.1 — some of them are [listed on the OpenSSL wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes). Converting software from 1.0 to 1.1 can be quite difficult...

Comment: @StephenKitt I am not saying the contrary, I am trying to push the OP to explain more why he really wants OpenSSL 1.0... which I think is far more important than achieving to use it finally.

Comment: Securing software using old versions (of openssl) known to suffer from security breaches is difficult too... :-)

Comment: I was answering your earlier comment asking for “a specific breakage/change of API between 1.0 and 1.1”, that’s all.

Comment: Please don’t spread FUD, 1.0 still gets security support.

Comment: @StephenKitt sorry, but you miss the point again... we still do not know why the OP needs version 1.0 nor which version specifically. I am afraid that the latest 1.0 will not even be a match, showing that the real problem beneath that we do not know about yet is really why the need of an older version... (and more specifically to your "FUD" critic: besides the breaches, the set of algorithms enabled by default for example will not be the same, and those disabled are for a good reason...)

Comment: More precisely, `1.0.2` being LTS, gets security support (until December 2019), not `1.0.0` nor `1.0.1` which are not supported any more at all by upstream OpenSSL.